# Error response is undefined when I get 504 error in axios

Tags: javascript, axios

If i got any 404 error then logging the error in catch block has that status code but if i get an 504 error from server then logging error.response in catch is undefined. Any reason why that happens?

```js
try {
  const response = await axios.request({
    method,
    url,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    },
    ...config,
  });
  return response;
} catch (error) {
  console.dir(error);
  if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
    const isNonAuthUrl = window.location.pathname.match(/\/verify\//);
    if (!isNonAuthUrl) {
      localStorage.clear();
      window.location.reload();
    } else {
      throw error;
    }
  } else {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've reproduced your issue here ~ https://jsfiddle.net/vjf85e94/. If I hit `https://httpstat.us/504/cors` with curl, it seems to work just fine. However when the request comes from the browser (using either `axios` or `fetch`), it fails due to CORS errors. The same thing happens for 502

Answer (score -4):

```
try {
  const response = await axios.request({
    method,
    url,
    timeout: 1000, //1000ms
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    },
    ...config,
  });
  return response;
} catch (error) {
  console.dir(error);
  if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
    const isNonAuthUrl = window.location.pathname.match(/\/verify\//);
    if (!isNonAuthUrl) {
      localStorage.clear();
      window.location.reload();
    } else {
      throw error;
    }
  } else {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

The default axios behaviour for timeout is 0 that means no timeout. So it will never be catched incase the request is taking more time. Try adding timeout specifically to the request then axios will abort the request with an error which can be catched in the catch block. In the above example I have added 1 sec timeout.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with axios timeouts. The server sends a response with status 504 and axios receives this response, and interprets it as an "error", so that the catch is called. If you set the axios timeout, axios will just stop to try receiving the response.